# Javascript code to kick off Spring WebFlow2 transition

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-webflow

Does anyone know of any javascript code that I can put on a radio button that will kick off a Spring WebFlow2 Transition event?

I am looking to kick off a transition to load values into a dropdown if the user clicks on a radio button... can someone please tell me if you seen this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation I think you want to use Ajax to refresh only part of your page. What I use is a function in my global js file:

```
function ajaxWebFlowSubmitGet(divID,pars,view) {
    new Ajax.Updater({success:divID},
                        view+"&date="+new Date().getTime(),
                        {   method:'get',
                            parameters:pars,
                            evalScripts:true,
                            onFailure:reportError,
                            requestHeaders: ['Accept','text/html;type=ajax']    
                        });
}
```

which you can use then in your code with

```
ajaxWebFlowSubmitGet('dropdownListDiv','_eventId=eventID&fragments=dropDownFragment',${flowExecutionUrl});
```

just put that 'ajaxWebFlowSubmitGet' function in your page and call it from your radiobutton.

- 'dropdownListDiv' is the div you want to get updated
- eventID is the name of the transition from your webflow you want to execute
- dropDownFragment is the name of the fragment you want to receive as a response (and to be put in your 'dropdownListDiv')

Comment: better now? what part don't you understand?

Comment: all that I am doing is kick off a transition type of the change of the radio button... I dont see why I need the divs etc etc

Comment: do you have a email address rptmat57

Comment: look at this question... http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129897-How-to-set-off-transition-from-javascript

Comment: email address is at gmail dot com

Comment: I thought you wanted to do that without having to reload the entire page every time.